# VSCode "go to definition" from a JS file not working with "require" in ".ts" files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a vscode project with a mix of .ts and .js files.
When running `tsc`, the code compiles as expected.
But, when hovering over a `require`d file in a `.ts` file in my code, vscode is not making the file clickable, and "go to definition" isn't taking me anywhere.

Here is a Minimal, Reproducible Example:

My tsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es2019",
        "allowJs": true,
        "strict": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.11.19",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

I have 2 files in my `src` folder:

utils.js:

```
module.exports = {
    count: 5,
};
```

and index.ts:

```
const utils = require('./utils');

console.log(utils.count);
```

When hovering over `'./utils'` in the require line, vscode doesn't give me the option to click into the required file.

It works if I change the index file to be a `js` file and not a `ts` file.

It works if I change `require` to using `import`.

But for some reason vscode doesn't know what to do with `require` in `ts` files.

What I'm missing in the vscode configuration?

Comment: Possibly related: [`maxNodeModuleJsDepth`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#maxNodeModuleJsDepth) and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5471. But also maybe not. I couldn't use that info to solve this.

Comment: Iterestingly it also works okay if the index.ts file is renamed to index.js.